# Copy-Item cmdlet should only copy difference

Tags: powershell, backup, copy-item

Im writeing a backupscript useing powershell. I know that i could just use robocopy or rsync but i would like to do this in powershell. The problem i have has to do with the copy-item cmdlet. What my script does:

- Read var's and fills them from a csv
- Pings destination host
- Checks if Outlook is open on source host and asks if it should close it
- Then it should copy some folders onto the destination

My problem is that it always does a full copy of all files. I would like it to only copy the files that were changed or do not exist on the destination.

The second problem i have is that in Win7 there are hidden systemfolders in "Users/Documents" that link to "My Pictures" and "My Videos". I dont need to copy these but i didnt manage to exclude them useing the exclude agrument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just some quick and general suggestion...

- *I would like it to only copy the files that were changed*

  I would copy the files comparing the source and destination modified date
- *The second problem i have is that in Win7 there are hidden systemfolders in "Users/Documents" that link to "My Pictures" and "My Videos". I dont need to copy these but i didnt manage to exclude them useing the exclude agrument.* :

  Do not use `copy-item` directly, but use the output of `get-childitem` without `force` parameter. This will prevent to copy hidden or system files.